# Unable to commit: There was a problem with the editor 'emacsclient -t' (dumb terminal)

Tags: magit, emacsclient

I get the following error when trying to amend a commit (same if I try to make a new commit):

```
  1 git … commit --amend
*ERROR*: Terminal type "dumb" is not powerful enough to run Emacs
error: There was a problem with the editor 'emacsclient -t'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

It was working earlier, the only thing I remember changing was trying out magit-gerrit. I removed that since and still doesn't work.

`emacsclient -t` works from the command line.

Magit 20171015.2104, Git 2.13.0, Emacs 24.4.2, gnu/linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, looks like I already solved it: `git config --list --global` contained `core.editor=emacsclient -t`. After removing -t it is working again.